# visualforce page for bootstrap stack columns

Tags: visualforce

Can anyone share some code how to display columns in stack order when it is responsive in visual force page.

Regards

Comment: have you already tried something ?  With so little info it's not quite clear what kind of answer you're expecting. There are likely many ways to make a page responsive, or use columns. Are you using any specific visualforce component ?  Please update your question with more info, help us help you!

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828435/stacking-bootstrap-columns-over-each-other